# Why my formdata gets wrong decode when i used scrapy to post it?

Tags: python, scrapy, http-post, decode

I wang to use scrapy and python 2.7.11 to stimulate a FormRequest to crawl http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/QiKan_ShouYe.htm?lan=en&journalId=IELEP0229&yp=2018

Here is my code:

```
def start_requests(self):         
    posturl = 'http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/essearch.ashx'
    url = 'http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/QiKan_ShouYe.htm?lan=en&journalId=IELEP0229&yp=2018'
    journalId = re.search(r'journalId=(.*?)&', url).group(1)
    yearNum = re.search(r'&yp=(\d+)', url).group(1)
    postdata = {
    "indexname" : "xw_qk", 
    "search" : "{0}/F(F_ReqNum)*{1}/F(F_YEAR)".format(journalId, yearNum),
    "page" : "0",
    "pagenum" : "20",
    "sort" : "",
    "type" : "content",
    }
    print journalId, yearNum
    print postdata
    self.logger.info('Visit_headpage........................')
    yield FormRequest(posturl,  formdata = postdata, callback = self.parse_item)
```

I need to post following data to the form:

```
indexname=xw_qk&
search=IELEP0229%2F(F_ReqNum)*2018%2F(F_YEAR)
&page=0&pagenum=20&sort=&type=content
```

to crawl the page correctly.

But my response is nothing, so I use fiddler to find the data posted form, and it is:

```
indexname=xw_qk&
search=IELEP0229%2FF%28F_ReqNum%29%2A2018%2FF%28F_YEAR%29
&page=0&pagenum=20sort=&&type=content
```

So it means these three signals get wrong decode:'(',  ')',  '*'.
But when I print formdata in scrapy log, it still in the right format:

```
 {indexname':'xw_qk', 'search':'IELEP0229/(F_ReqNum)*2018/(F_YEAR)',
 'page':'0', 'pagenum':'20', 'sort':'', 'type':'content}
```

So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Request(method='POST')` instead of `FormRequest()` because I had many troubles using this function.

And also try to append params directly into `posturl` like this

```
yield Request(url= posturl + "?search="+"{0}/F(F_ReqNum)*{1}/F(F_YEAR)".format(journalId, yearNum, method='POST')
```

and concatenate other params too,

Comment: This solution can't work for this site, could you please give an other solution? If i change to use python3, whether it would be work?

Answer (score 0):

They are sending the same thing (scrapy's FormRequest is only url-encoded) but what I think it's occurring is that it need to have a cookie received when you land first at `http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/QiKan_ShouYe.htm?lan=en&journalId=IELEP0229&yp=2018`, please try the following:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest


class IsticSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "istic"
    allowed_domains = ["istic.ac.cn"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/QiKan_ShouYe.htm?lan=en&journalId=IELEP0229&yp=2018']

    def parse(self, response):
        posturl = 'http://www.istic.ac.cn/suoguan/essearch.ashx'
        journalId = re.search(r'journalId=(.*?)&', response.url).group(1)
        yearNum = re.search(r'&yp=(\d+)', response.url).group(1)
        postdata = {
            "indexname" : "xw_qk",
            "search" : "{0}/F(F_ReqNum)*{1}/F(F_YEAR)".format(journalId, yearNum),
            "page" : "0",
            "pagenum" : "20",
            "sort" : "",
            "type" : "content",
        }
        yield FormRequest(posturl,  formdata = postdata, callback = self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        self.logger.debug('%s', data.keys())
```

It should output `[u'facets', u'hits', u'took']`

Comment: My output is the same as yours, so it means my form dosen't work.And i use other test tool,find that i don't need cookies to crawl my target data.

Comment: I don't follow, so you get `[u'facets', u'hits', u'took']`? (consider these are only the keys, not the real data), is there any value you're looking for to validate if it works/don't work?